# Symfony2 Doctrine Migration failed

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm new to Symfony. In Symfony 2.8.3 project I created mirgation file using

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:generate
```

But when I put some code in up() and down() methods and try to run

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

I get mistake:

> Migration 20160314161511 failed during Pre-Checks. Error Notice: Undefined offset: 1
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>    Notice: Undefined offset: 1

I tried to put different code by using "clear" SQL or via scheme, even left up/down methods with only //comments. But still no success.
DoctrineMigrationsBundle was installed and registered in AppKernel.php.
Here's the code of my aim mirgation:

```
namespace Application\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
class Version20160314161511 extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        $this->addSql(
            "CREATE TABLE tblProductData (
            intProductDataId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              strProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              strProductDesc varchar(255) NOT NULL,
              strProductCode varchar(10) NOT NULL,
              dtmAdded datetime DEFAULT NULL,
              dtmDiscontinued datetime DEFAULT NULL,
              stmTimestamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
              PRIMARY KEY (intProductDataId),
              UNIQUE KEY (strProductCode)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Stores product data'"
        );

    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        $this->addSql(
            'DROP TABLE tblProductData'
        );

    }
}
```

Here is the doctrine_migrations section of my config.yml:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: "%kernel.root_dir%/DoctrineMigrations"
    namespace: Application\Migrations
    table_name: migration_versions
    name: Application Migrations
```

doctrine section of config.yml I left with default value

When I use

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:status
```

I get  Available Migrations: 1 and  New Migrations: 1

Comment: Why are you making migrations files by hand. Why not "doctrine:migrations:diff"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to use :diff command, but I still have the same mistake. Also when I add new field to my entity, this field doesn't exist in created migration.

Comment: So, an unmodified, auto generated migration will throw this error?

Comment: Ok, something weird is going on. My suggestion: create a fresh symfony2 project, add the extact same version of doctrine migrations. Add one simple entitiy and autogenerate a migrations class. Than run it.
If that works fine than just transfer the migrations file to the test project and test it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in [zend-code](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-code) library which is a dependency of DoctrineMigrations and this issue appears only on Windows. The temporary workaround is to go to `vendors/zend-code/Generator/MethodGenerator.php#L96` and change:

```
protected static function clearBodyIndention($body) {
    ....
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $body);
    ....
    $body = implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
    ....
}
```

to:

```
protected static function clearBodyIndention($body) {
    ....
    $lines = explode("\n", $body);
    ....
    $body = implode("\n", $lines);
    ....
}
```

The developer of DoctrineMigrations is aware of this bug and you can find more info in this [issue](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/154#issuecomment-196557177).

At this point there is a [pull request](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-code/pull/46/commits/c2a11bbcd06042920649d0ab5164d7d3244105c8) to `zend-code` and hopefully this will be merged soon into the master which will then fix the problem.